# Why does IE8 fail to resolve my JQuery selector for a checked radio option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, radio-button

This following line works as expected in Firefox but IE returns 'undefined'.

```
var selectedChoice = $("input[name='my.test[0].SelectedOption']:checked", '#myForm').val();
```

Here is a standalone sample that you can run...

Note the problem seems to be the use of '.' and '[]' in the name of the radio element.  However this is how ASP.NET MVC renders them.  Here is an example which works fine in Firefox but fails in IE.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testing radio selection jquery in IE 8</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
      <input name="selected.Option[0]" id="selected_Option1" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />
      <label for="selected_Option1">Option 1</label>
      <br />

      <input name="selected.Option1" id="selected_Option2" type="radio" value="2" checked="checked" />
      <label for="selected_Option2">Option 2</label>
      <br />

      <input name="selectedOption[2]" id="selected_Option3" type="radio" value="3" checked="checked" />
      <label for="selected_Option3">Option 3</label>
      <br />

      <input name="selectedOption3" id="selected_Option4" type="radio" value="4" checked="checked" />
      <label for="selected_Option4">Option 4</label>
      <br />

      <span id="displaySelectedChoice1">No value selected.</span>
      <br />
      <span id="displaySelectedChoice2">No value selected.</span>
      <br />
      <span id="displaySelectedChoice3">No value selected.</span>
      <br />
      <span id="displaySelectedChoice4">No value selected.</span>
  </form>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var selectedChoice = $("input[name='selected.Option[0]']:checked").val();
    $('#displaySelectedChoice1').html('You have selected: ' + selectedChoice);

    var selectedChoice = $("input[name='selected.Option1']:checked").val();
    $('#displaySelectedChoice2').html('You have selected: ' + selectedChoice);

    var selectedChoice = $("input[name='selectedOption[2]']:checked").val();
    $('#displaySelectedChoice3').html('You have selected: ' + selectedChoice);

    var selectedChoice = $("input[name='selectedOption3']:checked").val();
    $('#displaySelectedChoice4').html('You have selected: ' + selectedChoice);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the 2nd, 3rd and 4th all work but the 1st returns 'undefined' for IE.  Its the only one with both '.' and '[]'.

Thanks

Comment: I think IE doesn't like the square braces in the selector.  Maybe you can try escaping them.

Comment: @Rocket pretty sure you're right on for this one.  Care to post a 1 line answer showing how to escape the character and I'll give you answer?  Thanks!

Comment: escape both the square brackets with **two** backslashes `\\\`

Comment: I updated the description with a more targeted example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to escape the square braces in the selector, I don't think IE likes 'em too much.  Also, you forgot to close the attribute selector.

```
var selectedChoice = $('input[name="my.test[0].SelectedOption"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
```

Or with escaped square braces and periods:

```
var selectedChoice = $('input[name="my\\.test\\[0\\]\\.SelectedOption"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
```

Yes, there are 2 backslashes.

Comment: Trying to escape with the double backslash doesn't work.  Firefox gives me an 'input not defined' and IE just doesn't work.  Other suggestion?  Your def looking at the right think.  If I rename my vars to not have the [ brackets it works in both IE and Firefox.

Comment: @Justin: I'm not sure, IE (as well as ASP.NET) is just stupid sometimes.

Comment: Haha very true.  It actually might be the '.' not the '['

Comment: @Justin try to escape the '.' then :-P

Comment: Check out the new example I posted where . and [] work independantly but NOT when used together...  STUPID IE!  Anyways I've found that escaping each of the '.' and '[' and ']' with \\ works in IE8 and Firefox!  Time to test IE7

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
var selectedChoice = 
    $('input[name="my.test[0].SelectedOption"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
```

**UPDATE:**

Replace your JS with this:

```
var $radio = $('input[name="my\\.test\\[0\\]\\.SelectedOption"]');

$radio.change(function() {

    $("#displaySelectedChoice")
        .html("You have selected: " + $radio.filter(":checked").val());  

});
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/p5Usf/)***

Comment: sorry same response I gave @Mark B.  My edit to make the question more clear added an error.  I've fixed the quotations.  The problem is def IE not liking the square brackets.

Comment: Btw ... I did test the \\ theory and it works in IE7 and IE8.

Comment: No problem my man! I learned something new about IE7. So weird that you can use the . or [] by themselves, but not together.  Who woulda thunk?

Answer (score 1):

Your select test is invalid javascript:

```
var selectedChoice = $('input[name='my.test[0].SelectedOption:checked', '#myForm').val();
                                   ^--embeded quote breaks the string
```

This should work better:

```
var selectedChoice = $("input[name='my.test[0].SelectedOption']:checked", '#myForm').val();
```

Note that the `:checked` portion is not in the name= portion

Comment: Sorry I just edited the question to put the quote in.  Unfortunetly I did it quick and in reality I have them as you showed already.  The problem is definitely the '[' and ']' characters.  But I'm not sure how to escape them yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to escape those `[]` inside your selector:

```
var selectedChoice = $("input[name='my.test\\[0\\].SelectedOption']:checked", '#myForm').val();
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

At the top it has an entire paragraph about escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I find your code pretty complicaded. Try something like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
      <input name="my.test[0].SelectedOption" class="test" type="radio" value="1"/>
      <label for="my_test_0__SelectedOption_1">Option 1</label>
      <br />

      <input name="my.test[0].SelectedOption" class="test" type="radio" value="2"/>
      <label for="my_test_0__SelectedOption_1">Option 2</label>
      <br />

      <input name="my.test[0].SelectedOption" class="test" type="radio" value="3"/>
      <label for="my_test_0__SelectedOption_1">Option 3</label>
      <br />
      <span id="displaySelectedChoice">No value selected.</span>
  </form>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(".test").change(
       function () {
         var value = $(this).val();
         $("#displaySelectedChoice").replaceTo("you choose: "+value)
       }
     )
  </script>
```

Comment: my example is a snippet of a much larger application.  My real code actually checks if the value matches a dynamically provided value and then either hides or shows another element altogether.  As Rocket mentioned the problem that needs to be solved here is how to get IE to recognize the select statement with the "[" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know wich version of jquery youre using, but even though I red about the new version of jquery that IE has a problem to "see" what you want with this ":checked".
Anyways avoid using this atribute for radio because, well the only checked radio is the one changed anyways.
My point is make a simpler code, it might help.