# Either an IE8 Selector or jQuery ButtonSet not consistently returning the proper result (Radio Buttons)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8

In IE8, when running the code below, the alert that comes up makes no sense.  Sometimes it returns the first button, sometimes another.

[I asked a similar question to this on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344663/jquery-1-7-1-buttonset-in-ie8-not-consistently-firing-the-change-event) Perhaps these are the same issue.  It's not clear, so I decided to ask a second question.

[This one is also related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062935/why-does-ie8-fail-to-resolve-my-jquery-selector-for-a-checked-radio-option)
[And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917677/jquery-returning-wrong-selected-radiobox)
 But they both miss the mark by enough that I don't know what to do now.

```
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#toolGroup").buttonset();
        $("#toolGroup").click(
        function () {
            alert($('input:radio[name=marker]:checked').val());
        }
        );
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="toolGroup">
        <input name="marker" type="radio" id="check1" value="tool1" checked /><label for="check1"><img src="/images/tool1.png" width="40" /></label>
        <input name="marker" type="radio" id="check2" value="tool2" /><label for="check2"><img src="/images/tool2.png" width="40" /></label>
        <input name="marker" type="radio" id="check3" value="tool3" /><label for="check3"><img src="/images/tool3.png" width="40" /></label>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you bound the click event to the container, it's getting triggered twice because of your `<label for='blah'>` label for your radio buttons. You can see this happening by replacing your function with this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toolGroup").click(function (e) {
        alert(e.target);
    });
});
```

Try binding your click events to the inputs instead. When you click the label, it triggers the click event​ on the input. So something like this should get you what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toolGroup").buttonset();
    $("#toolGroup input").click(function () {
        alert($('input:radio[name=marker]:checked').val());
    });
});
```

​
I tested it on IE8 and it worked for me binding to the inputs.

Edit: You can also substitute click() for change()

Comment: Re: Change -- check out this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344663/jquery-1-7-1-buttonset-in-ie8-not-consistently-firing-the-change-event